# Usage of special character "@" in JOLT template

Tags: json, jolt

Please help me in writing the jolt spec to get the expected output with special character "@" as shown below. When I place "@FirstName":"Names.FirstName" in the spec it is not working. Please help in resolving this.

JSON Input:

```
{
    "FirstName": "First"
}
```

Jolt Spec:

```
 [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "FirstName": "Names.FirstName"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "Names" : {
    "@FirstName" : "First"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Updated : As of Jolt version 0.0.21, the "shift" transform now allows special characters to escaped.

This Spec will allow "@FirstName" to be a key in the output.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "FirstName": "Names.\\@FirstName"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Great! It works also for `$` sign `\\$`